# How safe is it to play on snapshots?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Based on experience and general stability, would you say it is safe to play your main world on a snapshot build of Minecraft?

I am aware there's no guarantee of world integrity (but then again, neither is there any on the stable builds), but the question remains.

- Have you encountered irrecoverable chunk errors?
- Is upgrading to a stable build easily feasible?
- Is upgrading to other snapshot builds easily feasible?
- [When] should I backup my worlds?
- Are there other concerns to be had?

The new features are promising, and I don't feel like waiting anymore.

Comment: you can always back your worlds, then it is perfectly safe.

Comment: @joetheperson post that as an answer

Comment: rule of thumb: if the latest snapshot is more than 2 days old and no-one is complaining about bugs then it is safe to play

Comment: IMHO there are always bugs, i.e. playing on stable can *still* cause errors. Snapshots only have (much) *more bugs* than stable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is quite safe to play on these snapshots, because even popular multiplayer servers often upgrade to them.

It is no problem at all to upgrade to those snapshots: just download the *minecraft.jar* file and replace it in *.minecraft/bin*.

It is often good to wait a day or two after the first snapshot of a week (`**w**a`) has been released because they are often buggy and another snapshot (`**w**b`) can be released shortly afterwards.

I recommend to do backups regularly, maybe even as often as every 2 hours of playing, just to be safe. Making backups is easy: exit from world, compress the world folder to an archive and resume your game.

However, there are indeed some concerns:

- You can't go back to a previous build (without losing progress). New items will disappear in best case, or even cause worse problems.
- New additions can be unbalanced/overpowered. For example, Hoppers used to be crafted with Stone blocks, which are very cheap, but then were changed to use Iron. So you may feel uncomfortable about this...

Comment: Agree generally. An additional item for the list: Downgrading typically wipes out your achievements and statistics.

Comment: @KevinReid Not anymore. That was changed in 13w04a.